# Booting Linux from USB - countdown repeating

Tags: boot, linux-mint, bootable-media, liveusb

I have a Windows computer that I am trying to convert to Linux. I have downloaded the .iso file from Linux Mint 14 and have used UNetbootin to convert my USB to a bootable drive.

I choose to boot from Linux Mint and the login screen pops up with a countdown (10s). At 2s, the screen goes blank and it reboots to the login screen again (and continues to do so). I have read online that I am supposed to let it countdown, but it seems to fail at 2s.

Does anyone have any recommendations on this? Or know if I should put 'mint' in the username and what the default password is as a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you chosen the correct version between 32-bit and 64-bit, according to your hardware?

Comment: Yes - I confirmed 64bit.

Comment: I also have tried compatability mode.

Comment: Do you get the same looping countdown behavior if you boot the USB drive on a different computer?

Comment: I don't have another computer to try it out on unfortunately.

Comment: Try [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com) and if that exhibits the same behavior try with another USB stick and also different USB ports on your PC. As suggested above it would also help if you can test it on someone else's PC before reporting back (won't affect their OS in any way if you just boot into Linux and shut down), so we know for sure that it's not the USB installer's fault.